# android - http post request design

Tags: android, http, android-fragments, post

I implemented a http get request like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html).

Basically I added a fragment to my main activity. 
The fragment aggregated a AsyncTask object where the http get request was implemented.

I want to send a http post request now. 
What would be the best way to go about this?

Add another AsyncTask object to the same fragment?
Add another fragment?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the http://square.github.io/okhttp/ OkHTTP Library helps you with http requests. Although it's not a direct answer to your question, it really makes http requests easier.

Comment: Not an answer aswell, maybe try volley? https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: What about Retrofit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Volley Android Networking Library to post your data. Official document is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "Url",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Response Object: " + response.toString());

                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        PG.hideProgressDialog(pg);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        // Hide Progress Dialog
                        PG.hideProgressDialog(pg);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", strEmail);
                params.put("password", strPassword);
                params.put("deviceType", "ANDROID");
                params.put("deviceToken", fireBaseToken);
                Log.d(TAG, params.toString());
                return params;
            }

        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        MyApplication.getApp().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_json_obj);
```